How does Ryan enter a new time loop in "Happy Death Day 2U" if Sissy only fired once?
In Happy Death Day (2017) as well as in the sequel, Happy Death Day 2U (2019), it is shown that the day looping is Monday, September the 18th (caused by 'Sissy' firing).
How then, at the start of the sequel, does Ryan enter another time loop of his own on the following day even though the characters discover that Sissy fired up only once?

Been years since I've seen it, but aren't they in another dimension? IIRC Tree's mother is still alive in that dimension, for instance.

In the dimension that Ryan mentions he felt reliving the same day, it'd be improbable for Tree to also have re-lived the day prior given that Sissy fired only once. This is evident from the fact that Tree gives Ryan details about the loop.

Tree explains it to Ryan early on in the movie.

But, anyways, I finally kicked Lori's crazy ass out a window and killed her, which broke the loop, or so I thought. But now it only looks like it passed the loop on to you, and you're gonna be stuck reliving this day until we figure out how to stop it.

Yes, it's a big ball of wibbly wobbly, timey wimey explanation, sorry.
